# Installing RestEasy documentation is not clear--does maven install resteasy?

Tags: jax-rs, resteasy

> 3.1. Standalone Resteasy
>
> If you are using resteasy outside of JBoss AS 6, you will need to do a
>   few manual steps to install and configure resteasy. RESTeasy is
>   deployed as a WAR archive and thus depends on a Servlet container. We
>   strongly suggest that you use Maven to build your WAR files as
>   RESTEasy is split into a bunch of different modules. You can see an
>   example Maven project in one of the examples in the examples/
>   directory
>
> Also, when you download RESTeasy and unzip it you will see a lib/
>   directory that contains the libraries needed by resteasy. Copy these
>   into your /WEB-INF/lib directory. Place your JAX-RS annotated class
>   resources and providers within one or more jars within /WEB-INF/lib or
>   your raw class files within /WEB-INF/classes.

Hi, is my confusion justified? I am using JBoss 5 unfortunately.  Do I need to download RESTeasy and unzip it IF I am using Maven, as the documentation recommends?
Maven grabs all the dependencies that are needed to build a project, including the RESTEasy fraemwork, right? So why the contradiction here? Wish that the documentation would anticipate common questions and be written more clearly.

Answer (score 2):

If you search for RESTeasy at [Nexus](https://repository.sonatype.org/index.html#nexus-search;quick~resteasy) you can find V2.3.2.Final in the repository. The extension is war. Use the following POM to include it in the Maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
  <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs-war</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

- You can always download any dependency, put it manually in the lib directory and add it to the classpath (the second paragraph of the referenced documentation).
- When using Maven you should prefer to add the dependency to your pom.xml instead (the first paragraph of the referenced documentation).
- JBoss 6 includes RESTeasy, so with maven you want to add RESTeasy with scope "provided"
- It seams that JBoss 5 doesn't include RESTeasy, so you don't use scope "provided"

Scope [provided](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope) means that the container (JBoss) already comes with that library, so it doesn't have to be included in the release. However during development it has to be available since you compile against it.

**To summarize:**

When you are not using Maven (not recommended)

> Also, when you download RESTeasy and unzip it you will see a lib/
>   directory that contains the libraries needed by resteasy. Copy these
>   into your /WEB-INF/lib directory. Place your JAX-RS annotated class
>   resources and providers within one or more jars within /WEB-INF/lib or
>   your raw class files within /WEB-INF/classes.

When you are using Maven and not JBoss 6:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
  <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs-war</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

When you are using Maven and JBoss 6:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
  <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs-war</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.2.Final</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: If I don't have maven... is there any way to tell what jars these dependencies entail? As far as I can tell, it's just jaxrs-api-3.0.9.Final.jar, resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.17.Final.jar and resteasy-servlet-initializer-3.0.17.Final.jar ...

Comment: Just search under http://www.mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-jaxrs-war/2.3.7.Final and look at the dependencies